# Booting Ubuntu requires bitlocker?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows like I have done before on other PC's, but now when I boot it up, it tells me to insert the drive used for Bitlocker encryption. I've never used Bitlocker anywhere before on any of my PC's. Why is this happening?
It's alongside a non-OEM Windows 8 installation.

Comment: Apparently someone *has* used it.

Comment: Hmmm it's windows software so basically not an Ubuntu problem ;) might be of some help: http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux but if you want to get rid of it: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/turn-off-a-bitlocker-drive-on-windows-7/2b3d39c1-fb3e-44e1-a29a-d6afaba64b61